# Php application url

Tags: php, apache, url

I've a doubt. How can I configure my application to use www.mysite.com/myfolder instead of www.mysite.com/myfile.php?

I need to a create a profile page for every user registered to my PHP application but it's not so clear how can I do that. I've seen it's possibile with page frame, but, if possible, I prefrer don't use it.

Thanks for the suggestions!

cheers,
Andrea

Comment: Please clarify: what is meant by **use www.mysite.com/myfolder**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check out [`mod_rewrite`.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)  Your real url might be www.mysite.com/somename.php. But mod_rewrite can make the display url be www.mysite.com/somename/

For your user profiles, let the url be something like www.mysite.com/user.php?user_id=x and the display url be www.mysite.com/user/x/

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache's mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

when you go to a website like www.mysite.com/myfolder what apache is actually doing is finding the 'index file' for that folder.This is usually a file called index.html or index.php.

What i suggest using for something like user profiles is Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can alter this by changing [DocumentRoot in httpd.conf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#documentroot) or by using mod_rewrite - its a bit context dependent though really